# XML Validation with XSD schema - ValidationEventHandler info

Tags: xml, validation, c#-4.0, xsd, schema

I have a schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="address">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="country">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:minLength value="5"/>
                            <xs:maxLength value="8"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And simply XML File (it's only example):

```
<address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="address.xsd"> 
  <name>John Smith</name>
  <street>109 Abbey Close</street>
  <city>Hayes</city>
  <country>UK</country>
</address>
```

I am using `ValidationEventHandler`, but I need to code this to have clear info for client what is wrong. For example for country which has only 4 length, I will get error that field "country" has length less than MinValue.

But I want to give client information what means "MinValue", so for this example "5".

I was searching this for long time, but I couldn't find this.

Have you any idea how I can do it?

Now I have this code:

```
public static bool Validate(Stream xml, Stream xsd) 
{
    ClearErrorMessage();
    try {
        XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(xsd);
        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();

        schema.Add(null, tr);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ErrorHandler);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings);

        while(reader.Read()) {
        }
        reader.Close();

        if(numErrors > 0)
            throw new Exception(msgError);

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        msgError = "Validation failed\r\n" + msgError + " " + e.Message;
        return false;
    }
}

private static void ErrorHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args) 
{
    msgError = msgError + "\r\n" + args.Message + " " + args.Exception.LineNumber;
    numErrors++;
}
```

Comment: so you need to put a validation stating that if country is less than minimun value thrn it should show please enter a string greater than length 5?

Comment: but country is only example. There will be a lot of other fields.
I need show: "Field "country" has less length than MinValue = 5! Please correct this!"

Comment: tell exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Validate XML with schema and if there is Validation Error, I want return correct and clear info in feedback.

So when there is country with length 4 in XML, I want show client, that must be longer than 4

Comment: are you writing java code for this?

Comment: I want exactly what you wrote: "so you need to put a validation stating that if country is less than minimun value thrn it should show please enter a string greater than length 5? – Vikram Saini 10 mins ago"

How can I do it?

Comment: As I wrote in tag, I mean c#

Comment: just throw a manual exception in case your condition fails and set appropriate message in that exception\

Comment: I edited my question - I added code that I have right now. args.message returns that "value of Field is less than MinValue"

Comment: I was hoping to do the same thing, but the data provided to the Errror handler (sender and ValidationEventArgs) does point back to the schema rule that triggered the exception.  I don't think you can rely on XSD to provide the type of error message that you're trying to provide to your customers. I ended up having to write a custom validation after my schema validation.

Answer (score 0):

Most schema validators that I know of allow very little customisation of error reporting. To produce error messages designed for end users, you may be better off using Schematron, which has this as one of its main design goals.

Another approach would be to use Saxon's schema validator which has the ability to generate an XML validation report, which you could then transform into end-user terms using XSLT. For your example the validation report would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-report xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/validation"
                   system-id="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml">
   <error line="6"
          column="14"
          path="/Q{}address[1]/Q{}country[1]"
          xsd-part="2"
          constraint="cvc-datatype-valid.1">The content "UK" of element &lt;country&gt; does not match the required simple type. Value "UK" contravenes the minLength facet "5" of the type of element country</error>
   <meta-data>
      <validator name="SAXON-EE" version="9.8.0.3"/>
      <results errors="1" warnings="0"/>
      <schema file="test.xsd" xsd-version="1.1"/>
      <run at="2017-08-10T18:36:16.694+01:00"/>
   </meta-data>
</validation-report>
```

You could try and use XSLT pattern matching on this to make the messages more end-user friendly.

(My intent was eventually to add more semantic markup to this validation report to make this easier, for example writing `<facet>minLength</facet>` and `<facetValue>5</facetValue>`. But this remains an aspiration.)

Comment: Thank you for answer.

First way needs prepare xsd schema? I can't because I got this from client, and I must check converted data with this schema. 

Second way, I need pay to have version with schema validation, yes? :/

Comment: Yes, switching to Schematron is a significant change and that's why I suggested a second option. As for the second option, I assume you don't provide your services to your client for nothing, and neither do I.